# Can PhoneGap work as a server?

Tags: iphone, cordova

I am new to PhoneGap. I am trying to create an app for Iphone. I created two HTML5 pages in PhoneGap, say `Page1` and `Page2`. Page1 has a Html Form which uses the method `POST`.

**Question 1:** Where is the data from the form being posted?
**Question 2:** How can I retrieve the posted the data?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from your post that `Page 1` and `Page 2` are both HTML pages local to your application (and not on an HTTP server somewhere), then they are being fetched as File resources, not HTTP resources  As such, there is no way to retrieve POST'ed data.  (The [HTML 4 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3) goes so far as to say `User agent behavior for a value other than an HTTP URI is undefined.`
)

You may be able to work around this limitation by using GET instead of POST.  If you do this, you may be able to retrieve and parse the parameters from the URL via Javascript in `Page 2`, e.g. see [this article](http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html).